# How to I change global expect timeout in playwright

Tags: typescript, cucumber, playwright

I am writing in playwright using cucumber and typescript.

I need to change default expect wait time.

I noticed that each matcher, like `toBeVisible()` has their own timeouts, but also read in manual, that expect can be configured like this (from manual)

```js
const slowExpect = expect.configure({ timeout: 10000 });
await slowExpect(locator).toHaveText('Submit');
```

However I want the change to be global.
There is also extend field in `Expect` type.

```js
//...
  extend(matchers: any): void;
  configure: (configuration: {
    message?: string,
    timeout?: number,
    soft?: boolean,
  }) => Expect;
//...
```

What is the best way to achieve it?

Should I export `slowExpect` ,or should I use extend in some config file and also export it?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the global expect timeout in the config and that will apply to all assertions unless you override it in a specific expect statement.

```
import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
  expect: {
    timeout: 10 * 1000,
  },
});
```

Comment: I guess @hetacz is using the runner from Cucumber, and Playwright as a library. If this is the case the call to `defineConfig` is a no-op (it works only when the Playwright runner is used).

Comment: any one got a solution for this when we use it with the cucumber test runner?

Comment: for me doesn't event the 'slowExpect' example work